# Setting scope values inside bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Am using bootstrap along with Angular JS Frameworks in my project. I have assigned some expressions inside modal for text boxes and other things.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="FirstName" value="{{firstname}}">
```

When am trying to assign values inside modal, it doesn't works. Let' say

```
ClickFunction(args)
{
   $scope.firstname = args.FirstName
}
```

But the value was shown inside bootstrap modal only when I apply

```
$scope.$apply.

 ClickFunction(args)
    {
       $scope.firstname = args.FirstName;
       $scope.$apply.

    }
```

May I know what was the reason?

Comment: When will you call this ClickFunction() ?

Comment: After page gets loaded and on click of a button which contains Json data. I will set that json data to the modal . Both modal and button are inside same controller only.

Comment: If I remove value="{{firstname}}" then how does I modal show text box. Even I have tried that too but not works. Only after $scope.$apply

Comment: Can you provide controller code and modal html

Comment: Can you paste your code?